# worker_threads not run when start nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, web-worker

I'm studying nodejs worker_threads. I want to revoke a worker when the server start like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node
const bole = require('bole');
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('./config');

// Use whichever logging system you prefer.
// Doesn't have to be bole, I just wanted something more or less realistic
const app = require('./app');

bole.output({ level: 'debug', stream: process.stdout });
const log = bole('server');

log.info('server process starting');

// Note that there's not much logic in this file.
// The server should be mostly "glue" code to set things up and
// then start listening
app.listen(config.express.port, config.express.ip, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    log.error('Unable to listen for connections', error);
    process.exit(10);
  }
  log.info(`express is listening on http://${config.express.ip}:${config.express.port}`);

  const worker = new Worker('./worker.js');
  worker.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

Here is my worker file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
import { parentPort } from 'worker_threads';

parentPort.on('message', data => {
});

parentPort.postMessage('Hello world!');
```

But it does not work. I tried other samples on the Internet and they worked well but failed to implement them to my server. I'm running node v12.0.0 .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, not really sure how you are providing the path to your worker file.
You have imported 'path' module but you have never used it.
so maybe look into that.

Secondly and more importantly, workers return a promise, so bind your code in a promise that gets resolved when the mainThread received from worker.